# update data in Array of Structs with data in other Array of Struct

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

Let's say I have struct :

```swift
struct Planet {
    var id : UUID
    var name: String
    ...
}
```

I have an array of such structs which is constructed from data fetched from a database. I use this for a form in a browser where the user can:

- edit the fields (eg change the name of Planet)
- create one or more new Planets

at this time the user may not delete a Planet but it would be great if the solution would support that too

When the form is submitted I get an array with those structures (the order is also not the same as the original). What is the best/most efficient way to do update the data in the original array with the data from the second.

My current idea is:

1. map the original array to a dictionary with key= id, value= aPlanetStructure
2. loop over the second array (with the edited data) and if that 'key' can be retrieved in the dictionary (=data from first array)-> update the struct there, if not create an additional planet in the first array.

I'm not sure if this is a good approach, it seems like there could be a more efficient way (but I can't think of it). It would also not support deleting a Planet

Comment: You just need to get the index of your planet and update the corresponding element

Comment: unfortunately it is not that simple: the order from the form is different than the order in de database (it comes back totally unsorted). + index to index would als give problems if one is deleted

Comment: If you are also responsible for the backend, you could send three dictionaries `deleted`/`added`/`modified` with the appropriate data. Alternatively load the entire data set and use diffable data source.

Comment: When sending from database to form : it is no use as the user will change it and at that time we don't know what is in which category. When sending it back from the form we can not split it into 3 dictionaries as the form is send by a HTML submit as a whole

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you can separate out the elements of the array by action, you'll make your life easier.

For example:

```
var created= [Planet]()
var updated= [Planet]()
var deleted = [Planet]()
```

In your UI layer, when an edit is made, add the edited planet to the
updated array, when a planet is deleted, add it to the deleted array, etc.

Submit all 3 arrays with your form.

Loop over the results of each and pass too your create, update, and delete methods that access your database.

That will require restructuring your form code a bit, but... in general it's easier in your UI layer to tell whether someone is doing a create, an update, or a delete, than it is to mush them all together and try to figure it out after the fact by doing comparisons.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible as the UI layer has to be pure HTML

Comment: pure HTML... with no javascript?

Comment: at this time not

Comment: then yep, you're stuck brute forcing it like you suggested with the arrays. Unless your goal is to persist back to the database, in which case sometimes you can let the database do the heavy lifting. MySQL for example lets you do UPSERTS like so: https://www.techbeamers.com/mysql-upsert/

Postgres like so:

https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-upsert/

etc.

Comment: That is what I guessed, but the question was more if this approach is the good brute force method... or are there any better options in Swift. I'm not really a Swift expert.

Comment: If you like SQL, my gut would be that offloading some of that comparison to the database might result in less code. SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE ID IN (?,?,?) would give you a quick list of the items that had been changed.  SELECT ? FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE WHERE ID = ?) would give you a list of items that were up for deletion and/or addition. (That's syntax for DB2, but other DB's have similar concepts of a dummy table.)  

Kinda depends on if you love doing heavy lifting in databases or if you find for loops easier to maintain.

Comment: This would be an option if the dataset was large enough. However with recordsets varying between 3 and 30 I don't think it's worth the extra research to get this working. But thank you anyway for thinking along!